# View Controllers accumulate memory even when dismissed, in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I can't seem to find any resolutions to this. I've made all my objects 'weak' in both view controllers in question. I have included dismiss functions and even the 'RemoveFromSuperView' function. I tried them all without luck. I also tried making the button action 'modal', 'push', ect. None made any difference.

Essentially as I move from controllers, **memory seems to just accumulate more and more**. On both controllers I'm simply using WebView's. I rack up over 100MB of memory usage after some time navigating between views. Eventually the app runs out of memory and crashes.

How do I either **clear all memory accumulated by the app** or properly **dismiss/kill all inactive View Controllers and clear all memory associated**?

Comment: Override dealloc method for the viewController you're dismissing and check if it gets called.

Comment: You are holding refs from one object to the next and this is likely creating a ref count loop. The main thing to not do is have any View Controller hold a ref to another View Controller. Just don't do that and you will be a lot better off.

Comment: How do I manually override dealloc method?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you override dealloc method

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [_object release]; 
    [super dealloc];
}
```

where _object is whatever property you initialized.